# Warum heißt der Gasometer so?

Tags: etymology, greek

Der Gasometer ist nichts anderes als ein großer Behälter, der Gas enthält.

[image]Aus dem Griechischen abgeleitete deutsche Begriffe die den Bestandteil "meter" enthalten, bezeichnen meistens entweder ein Mass oder ein Hilfsmittel zum Messen (Hexameter, Mikrometer, Amperemeter,...)

Das im Bild gezeigte Gebäude (übrigens ein Schmuckstückchen aus Wien), scheint mir keins von beidem zu sein. Warum bezeichnet man den Gasometer also so?

Comment: Das heißt so, weil es wirklich *technisch als Niederdruckspeicher für das aus Kohle gewonnene Stadtgas* ausgeschrieben war. Es war ein großer Gasbehälter, siehe [Wikipedia-Eintrag](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gasometer_(Wien)).

Comment: @deHaar Ich verstehe die Frage so: Was hat ein Gaso**meter** mit Messvorgängen oder Maßeinheiten zu tun, also mit den Bedeutungen, die im Duden unter [-meter](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/_meter) aufgelisted sind

Comment: @Marzipanherz Ja, da verstehst du richtig. Und du scheinst die Frage sogar gelesen zuhaben...

Comment: @tofro Ich geb mein Bestes :) Vielleicht ist der Dudenlink ganz nützlich um das eigentliche "Problem" zu verdeutlichen :)

Comment: @Marzipanherz Dann nehmen wir den nächsten [Wikipedia-Artikel](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gasbeh%C3%A4lter#Niederdruckgasbeh%C3%A4lter), der folgendes beinhaltet: *Die Bezeichnung Gasometer wurde zum ersten Mal von dessen Erfinder, dem französischen Chemiker Antoine Laurent de Lavoisier, verwendet. Ihm gelang 1789 die Entwicklung eines Behälters, der zur Speicherung von Gasen geeignet ist und mit dem Namen **gazometre** benannt wurde. Der erste Gasometer (Gaszähler – nicht Gasbehälter) wurde 1815 von William Clegg (Assistent von William Murdoch), einem Pionier der Gasbeleuchtung, geplant.*.

Comment: Hast Du eigentlich diesen Eintrag zum Begriff [Gasometer](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gasbeh%C3%A4lter#Begriff_Gasometer) schon gesehen? Ich weiß, dass Wikipedia-Artikel als Referenz nicht gern gesehen sind, aber vielleicht hilft das ja auch: _[...] bezeichnete ursprünglich ein Messgerät (siehe auch Saturometer), welches den Zweck hat, bestimmte Eigenschaften, insbesondere den Druck eines Gases, zu messen_

Comment: In genau dem abgebildeten Gasometer habe ich von 2001 bis 2013 gewohnt

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Wie [die Webseite](http://www.gasometer-city.eu/technik.htm) des Ensembles verrät, waren Gasometer so beschaffen, dass sie bei höherem Füllgrad weiter aus dem Boden ragten, sie also selbst ein aus der Ferne ablesbares grobes Messinstrument darstellten. (Das kann man bei der ummauerten Variante aus Wien nur erahnen, bei den nackten Stahlgerüsten ist das offensichtlicher). Auf der Seite steht außerdem:

> Die Anzeige des Gas-Füllstandes erfolgte über die sogenannte Gasometer-Uhr (Bild rechts). Der eigentliche Namensgeber der Gasometer. Ein mechanisches Anzeigeinstrument, das über ein Gestänge mit den sich bewegenden Glockenteilen verbunden war. Die Skala zeigt bis 90, das ist der maximale Füllstand von 90.000 m³ Gas.

Ein nettes Zitat aus der englischen [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gas_holder):

> Despite the objections of Murdoch's associates that his so-called *gasometer* was not a meter but a container, the name was retained and came into general use.

Comment: Ich bin gerade total geflasht vom Know-How unserer Urahnen o.O

Comment: Ich bezweifle, dass sich tatsächlich der gesamte Backsteinbau bewegt hat (vergleiche auch Huberts Antwort). Somit war aus der Ferne immer das gleiche Gebäude zu sehen.

Answer (score 3):

In dem Wiener Gasometer, der in der Frage von tofro abgebildet ist, habe ich von 2001 bis 2013 gewohnt.

Dieses konkrete Gebäude besteht aus 4 Türmen, die Ende des 19. Jahrhunderts erbaut wurden. (Man hat damals übrigens mit dem Dach begonnen: Dessen Stahlkonstruktion wurde auf dem Boden zusammengeschweißt. Bei Bau hat man es mit hydraulischen Hebern angehoben, eine Schicht Ziegel darunter gelegt, wieder angehoben usw.)

Jeder Turm bestand am Boden aus einer großen Wasserwanne, in die ein großer Stahlzylinder gestellt wurde, der weder Boden noch Deckel hatte. Er hatte eine doppelte Wand, die ebenfalls mit Wasser gefüllt war, diese Wand war unten zu und oben offen. In diesem Zwischenraum steckte ein zweiter Stahlzylinder, der gleich gebaut war, und in dessen Wand ein dritter, der allerdings dann oben geschlossen war. Durch diese Bauweise konnten sich die beiden oberen Zylinder wie ein Teleskop auf- und abbewegen, und das Wasser am Boden und in den Wänden war die Gasdichtung.

Dadurch hatte jeder der vier Gasbehälter ein variables Volumen, denn das Erdgas, das darin gespeichert war, wurde nicht mit Überdruck gespeichert, sondern annähernd mit normalem Luftdruck.

Rund um diese Stahlbehälter wurde eine Ziegelmauer gebaut, die jedoch niemals mit dem Gas in Berührung kam. Sie musste nur das Dach tragen, gegen die Witterung schützen und sollte einigermaßen schön ausschauen, soweit das für einen Industriebau möglich war.

Die Ziegelmauer verbarg aber auch den Blick auf die beweglichen Stahlzylinder im Inneren, daher konnte man ohne Hilfsmittel von außen den Füllstand nicht ablesen. Man benötigte also ein Messgerät, das den Füllstand anzeigt, also einen *»Gasometer«*.

Der Gasometer ist eigentlich die Messuhr, die außen am Gebäude angebracht ist, und die den Füllstand angezeigt hat. Beim Wiener Gasometer hat jeder der vier Türme eine eigene Messuhr, die geschätzte 2 bis 3 Meter Durchmesser hat.

Nach dieser Messuhr wurde dann das ganze Gebäude benannt.

---

Die Wiener Gasometer wurden übrigens Ende des 20. Jahrhunderts in eine Mischung aus Einkaufszentrum und Wohnhausanlage umgebaut, und im Sommer 2001 zogen dort die ersten Bewohner ein. Die oben erwähnten Stahlzylinder wurden ausgebaut, und in die übrig gebliebenen Ziegel-Zylinder wurden Wohnungen eingebaut. Insgesamt leben jetzt ca. 1500 Menschen im Wiener Gasometer.